# Content view content update app crashes in xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I create the xamarin form project and update the content view content multiple time.

Its correctly update for android. But it not work for iOS

I have update the Contentview content when click the button like that

```
contentView.content = mVview;
```

Please find the stack trace

```
wrapper managed-to-native


at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName,`/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKi1
```

when i put try catch, i got this stack trace

```
 at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EditorRenderer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x00003] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\EditorRenderer.cs:28 
  at Foundation.NSObject.Dispose () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:133 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x001c4] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:153 
  at Foundation.NSObject.Dispose () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:133 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.DisposeModelAndChildrenRenderers (Xamarin.Forms.Element view) [0x00038] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:322 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.HandleChildRemoved (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ElementEventArgs e) [0x00007] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:433 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnDescendantRemoved (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00008] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:600 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnDescendantRemoved (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00022] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:603 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnDescendantRemoved (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00022] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:603 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnChildRemoved (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:367 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnChildRemoved (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:578 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnInternalRemoved (Xamarin.Forms.View view) [0x00012] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:413 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.InternalChildrenOnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x0002f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Layout.cs:377 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00012] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs:288 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, System.Object item, System.Int32 index) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs:351 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].RemoveItem (System.Int32 index) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs:205 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[T].Remove (T item) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplateUtilities.OnContentChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldValue, System.Object newValue) [0x0001a] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplateUtilities.cs:63 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00108] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:584 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x0014b] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:378 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0005f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:531 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:83 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ContentView.set_Content (Xamarin.Forms.View value) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ContentView.cs:11 
  at EgnatiumFull.Pages.QuestionAnswerPage.UpdateTheQuestionLayout () [0x00144] in /Volumes/MS/prjects/Egnatium/EgnatiumFinal/EgnatiumFinal/EgnatiumFinal/Pages/QuestionAnswerPage.cs:539 
  at EgnatiumFull.Pages.QuestionAnswerPage+<OnAppearing>c__async1.MoveNext () [0x0007e] in /Volumes/MS/prjects/Egnatium/EgnatiumFinal/EgnatiumFinal/EgnatiumFinal/Pages/QuestionAnswerPage.cs:383 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at EgnatiumFinal.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/saifamily/Documents/14_2_17/EgnatiumFinal/EgnatiumFinal/EgnatiumFinal.iOS/Main.cs:17 xa
```

Comment: please show the relevant code which causes the crash

Comment: @Jason are you need any extra coding about this issues? could you please help me? I spend more than 3 days on this issue

Comment: have you tried wrapping it in a try/catch?

Comment: @Jason please find my stack trace now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution in my own way, i think i don't know is this correct way but in my case it work perfectly

I rendererd the list view for ios and overide the methods dispose with try/catch statement

```
 protected override void Dispose() 
    {
        try{
        base.Dispose();
         }
       Catch(Exception ex)
         {
            return;
         }
    }
```